# I cant make a call in a motorola moto e4

Tags: java, android

i try to make a automatic call in this device with this code

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Class

```
  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

it works in other devices like samsung j7 or LG pheonix, but in this, the call never start.

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean the call never starts?  Do you mean it launches the dialer and doesn't immediately call?  That's up to the dialer app, but in my experience that's the norm-  it would bring up the dialer prepopulated with the number and make the user press the call button.  This is to avoid 900 scams.  If you mean something else, please explain.

Comment: thats right, the app have this behaivior "it would bring up the dialer prepopulated with the number and make the user press the call button." But i need the phone make the call automatic when i press a button in my app,without waiting for an user press the call button when the dialler appers. 

So the process will be,
1) press the button
2) Start the call

Comment: There is no way to do that via intent, most dialers require the extra press. You could do it directly, but only with root access.

Comment: so, i need to make a method that allows me to click that button when appers?can i press a botton whos outside my app?

Comment: No, you can't.  For one thing, the button won't be int he same place on all dialers.  There's actually a reason why Android doesn't allow this-  to prevent you from dialing 1-900 numbers or other per minute charge numbers and causing the customer huge bills.  SO expect any way you find to be taken away as quickly as you find it.

Comment: well, thanks for the info bro, let me see what can i do

Answer (score 0):

Which is the OS version of Moto E4?

There are two types of intents that you can use for calls:

**- ACTION_DIAL**
Where the app's dialer is launcher with the number you want to call to (requires user action)

**- ACTION_CALL**
The call starts automatically.

According to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) although it's not the recommended approach, you shouldn't have any problems. The only thing that it's mentioned is that you need to have the call permission granted by the user (and not only on the Manifest file) for Android M and upwards.